# Is it possible to encode subtitles into a MP4 file for use on a PS3?

Tags: mp4, subtitles, ps3

What's the correct or most up-to-date way of doing this?
What program do I use?

I want to watch a MP4 on my PS3 with subtitles 'hardcoded', because the PS3 doesn't recognize srt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Handbrake video converter; it's a great free program. Handbrake has two options for handling subtitles, they can be softcoded in as seperate video tracks, or they can be hardcoded into the video itself.[(REF)](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/Subtitles)

When you're setting up a conversion job in Handbrake, go to the `subtitles` tab, and check the box for `burn in` on the subtitle track you want hardcoded.

Comment: I did this, it took about 3 hours to re-encode, but the PS3 still would not show the subtitles. If you select the subtitles (srt) file it doesn't show the 'burn in' option. If you select 'add' i.e.  to add subtitles, it doesn't give an option to add the srt file.

Answer (score 0):

We are having several application in market to do the work. Where you can hardcode subtitle using VLC media player itself. Please check the below link for further details.

http://rikardo.kinja.com/how-to-hardcode-subtitles-using-vlc-and-rendered-mp4-fi-1438028334

Hope this helps

Comment: I believe it's against board rules/etiquette to give an answer in the form of a link

Comment: resulting file doesn't play on the ps3, screen stays black. does play on pc though